# Camera is overlapping the Navigation Drawer - Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-camera

I need help again guys. It seems my camera activity(which is a fragment) is overlapping my navigation drawer. I don't know how to solve this.

This is my how it looks like:

[image: Click Here]

This is my code for CameraFragment.java:

```
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {

    private Camera mCamera = null;
    private CameraView mCameraView = null;


    View v;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_first_fragment, container, false);


        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();//you can use open(int) to use different cameras
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCameraView = new CameraView(getActivity(), mCamera);//create a SurfaceView to show camera data
            FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
            camera_view.addView(mCameraView);//add the SurfaceView to the layout
            //  camera_view.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------camera

        return v;
    }

    private class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        private Camera mCamera;

        public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            mCamera = camera;
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            //get the holder and set this class as the callback, so we can get camera data here
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_NORMAL);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            try{
                //when the surface is created, we can set the camera to draw images in this surfaceholder
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceCreated " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            //before changing the application orientation, you need to stop the preview, rotate and then start it again
            if(mHolder.getSurface() == null)//check if the surface is ready to receive camera data
                return;

            try{
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            } catch (Exception e){
                //this will happen when you are trying the camera if it's not running
            }

            //now, recreate the camera preview
            try{
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("ERROR", "Camera error on surfaceChanged " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            //our app has only one screen, so we'll destroy the camera in the surface
            //if you are using with more screens, please move this code your activity
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
        }
        }
    }
```

This is my activity_camera.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_first_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.dcar.FirstFragment">
<!--
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_second_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.dcar.MainActivity"
    >
-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_view"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        >

    </FrameLayout>
<!--
</FrameLayout>
-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();



     NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

Fragment home = new FirstFragment();
        FragmentManager FM = getFragmentManager();
        FM
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, home)


                  .commit();
}

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        if (id == R.id.action_ar) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new CameraFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
        else if (id == R.id.action_map) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new SecondFragment())
                    .commit();

        }
        else if (id == R.id.action_direction) {

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.content_frame, new ThirdFragment())
                    .commit();

        }
```

My activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: What navigation drawer? You've nothing in your layout that would create a drawer, in the usual sense of "drawer".

Comment: I do have. But i did not paste it here. As you can see in the "Click here" I put the name  Navigation drawer(color blue) in order for you to identify it.

Comment: If you have a problem involving a drawer, we need to see how the drawer is implemented. Just an image isn't going to suffice. You should also include any `Fragment` transactions you've got happening in the `Activity`.

Comment: Ok sir. Done editing btw. =)

Comment: Hmm, everything seems OK, assuming `content_frame` is inside `app_bar_main`. Do the rest of your `Fragment`s work as expected? Also, any particular reason you're not using support `Fragment`s?

Comment: Yes. Everything works perfectly except the CameraFragment. There's no reason at all. I've been following tutorials in YouTube and other websites and mostly some are just using fragment....In my second fragment the navigation drawer is showing perfectly. It seems the problem is in the CameraFragment?. @_@

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. This works for me

```
drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        drawerLayout.bringChildToFront(drawerView);
        drawerLayout.requestLayout();
    }
    ...
}
```